Windows 11 Pro does not accept a local and a remote connection on the same PC
I have a computer with Windows 11 Pro.
I need two people to be logged in at the same time: Jhon logged in locally and Carl logged in via RDP (each with their respective accounts).
The problem is that if Carl is connected via RDP to his account and Jhon accesses his account locally, a message appears saying that the account is already in use. In Carl's RDP access, a message appears asking to accept Jhon's connection, but when accepting, the RDP connection is dropped.
I know that it is not possible to use the same account locally and via RDP at the same time. But in this case, there are two different accounts, one accessing locally and the other via RDP, and even then they kind of get in the way.

Are you trying to BLOCK the RDP session if you're interactively logged into the target machine, or are you trying to have BOTH sessions log in successfully? Windows, by default, only allows a single session to be active at a time. There is a special license required to use "Terminal services", though there are work arounds. But please EDIT your post to make your intent more clear.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Windows 11 Home and Professional only allows one user to remotely be logged in, what you want, is impossible with those editions. If your already logged into the desktop a Remote Desktop connection will and is expected to logout the user already logged in since on those editions only one user can be active.

Thank you everyone for the responses.
I edited the question. I hope it becomes clearer now.

Home won't allow RDP at all @Ramhound :D

@JourneymanGeek - Yeah, but my point stands, 1 or less.

Multi seat computing is a different, even more fun thing. This is simple concurrent settings.

There are third-party tools that might meet your needs, e.g., https://www.splashtop.com/products/business-access, https://www.zoho.com/assist/pricing.html, https://www.helpwire.app/blog/allow-multiple-remote-desktop-connections-windows-10/, etc. This site cannot recommend software, and I heven't tried them though.

That's by design - you can't log in 'twice', even with different accounts into a non server instance. I remember its documented somewhere but I can't quite find it. The feature you're looking for is referred to as concurrent sessions and the 'regular' versions of windows professional and enterprise don't support it.
Microsoft kind of wants you to buy a server version and associated licences, though supposedly there's a 'enterprise' SKU that'll let you do this that's Azure only, so its very much a product differentiation thing.
You essentially need either server with a terminal server licence or (for non production use, and you're willing to deal with a certain level of risk - including violating your EULA) there's tools that'll patch your terminal server dll, or do other things to allow concurrent logins. The one I've heard recommended is RDP wrapper, but its not been updated in a long time -this other post might be a useful starting point if you're looking at it
